# How do sites bypass a browsers 'block popup / under' settings

Tags: javascript, html, popup, browser-security

When visiting some sites you close the browser to find a load of popups sitting behind it usual for online casinos and 'MacKeeper'.

How are these bypassing the browsers popup settings ? I thought they might be opening the pages in a new window using javascript to automate it and `target="_blank"` to get it in a new window, but i thought `target="_blank"` usually opens the webpage in a new tab as opposed to a new page hidden behind the current page you are using.. any ideas ?

Comment: `window.open()` and `target="_blank"` have no control over how the popup is opened; it's determined by the browser's settings. Although I've found that passing a height/width to `window.open` will "force" it to a window (not a tab) in some/all browsers

Comment: I think most of these *pop unders* are delivered by huge gray-market ad networks.  The scripts try 20 different things to open up a new window, some of which may work on different browsers and versions.  They'll keep updating the script as browsers continue to evolve and prevent things.  It's really an evil art.

Answer (score 1):

They just open the popup on the click event for the document.  Browsers usually allow popups from user initiated events (like button clicks).

If you use 2 monitors and browse on the non main monitor you can always catch those pesky popunders before they load.